# How to store and query an SQL View in cache

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq, caching

I am trying to store an SQL View in cache, though I keep getting errors no matter what I try...

When I run the code below, it errors on the take command.

```
Unable to cast object of type '<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[View_UserSearch]' to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[View_UserSearch]'.
```

Here is the code:

```
    Using ctx As New NdpDataClassesDataContext
        If System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache("View_UserSearch") Is Nothing Then
            Dim query = From vw In ctx.View_UserSearches

            System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("View_UserSearch", query.ToArray, Nothing, DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 1, Date.Now), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.AboveNormal, Nothing)
        End If

        Dim cacheQuery = DirectCast(System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache("View_UserSearch"), View_UserSearch()).Where(Function(a) a.LoweredEmail.Contains(e.Text)).OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.UserID)

        ' Getting the total number of items that start with the typed text
        e.ItemsCount = cacheQuery.Count

        cacheQuery = cacheQuery.Skip(e.ItemsOffset).Take(10)

        ComboBox2.DataSource = cacheQuery
        ComboBox2.DataBind()

        ' Calculating the number of items loaded so far in the ListBox
        e.ItemsLoadedCount = e.ItemsOffset + cacheQuery.Count
    End Using
```

---

### **EDIT - SOLUTION:**

I was able to fix this by changing this line:

```
Dim cacheQuery = DirectCast(System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache("View_UserSearch"), View_UserSearch()).Where(Function(a) a.LoweredEmail.Contains(e.Text)).OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.UserID)
```

to:

```
Dim cacheQuery = DirectCast(System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache("View_UserSearch"), View_UserSearch()).Where(Function(a) a.LoweredEmail.Contains(e.Text))
cacheQuery = cacheQuery.OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.UserID)
```

This changes the variable cacheQuery from an IOrderedEnumerable to an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
Dim query = From vw In ctx.View_UserSearches
```

do

```
Dim query = ctx.View_UserSearches
```